# What is exactly the difference between "all" and "any"?

Tags: meaning

I have problems understanding this two sentences:

1. There are no entailment relations for **any** of an omnipotent, omniscient being‘s
   allowances of evils E1…En between his allowances of those evils and greater
   (possible) goods.
2. There are not entailment relations for **all** of an omnipotent, omniscient being‘s
   allowances of evils E1…En between his allowances of those evils and greater
   (possible) goods.

Answer (score 2):

'All' means every possible member of a group.
'Any' means one possible member of a group.